# about javascript / jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find the syntax something like this anywhere:

```
var mz = jQuery.noConflict();
mz('#zoom01, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
```

This means: `jQuery.noConflict()('#zoom01, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();`

And something like this:

```
$(window)[this.off?'off':'on']("scroll", fixDiv );
```

So, I'm wondering about the syntax something like of these:

`jQuery.noConflict()(syntax)` and `$(window)[syntax](syntax)` and I also think there might be something like this `$(selector){syntax}`

Can anyone elaborate of those syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to start is the documentation

[$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.

In other words, `noConflict()` sets a variable to equal `jQuery`, so this

```
var mz = jQuery.noConflict();
mz('#zoom01, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
```

is the same as

```
$('#zoom01, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
```

or

```
jQuery('#zoom01, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
```

`noConflict()` does not directly take selectors, it's just a function that sets jQuery in a certain scope to a variable so you can have multiple versions of jQuery (which you shouldn't) or use other libraries that also uses `$` for something, it does not mirror the selector engine or anything else, even if it might seem so at first glance, it simply returns an instance of `jQuery`

---

In javascript there is dot notation and bracket notation, so an object can be accessed as

```
object.propertyName
```

or

```
object['propertyName']
```

as everything in javascript is an object, even jQuery methods, they can be accessed as

```
$('#element').fadeIn(200);
```

or

```
$('#element')['fadeIn'](200);
```

it's the same thing, so doing

```
$(window)['on']("scroll", fixDiv );
```

is the same as

```
$(window).on("scroll", fixDiv );
```

the advantage of using brackets is that they can contain any string, even variables, or in this case ternary statements, or the returned result of a function

```
var event = 'on';
$(window)[event]("scroll", fixDiv );
```

or

```
var event = this.off ? 'off' : 'on';

$(window)[event]("scroll", fixDiv );
```

that one also uses `this`, which in the global scope would be `window`, and it's the same as

```
$(window)[this.off ? 'off' : 'on']("scroll", fixDiv );
```

The ternary statement itself is just a fancy condition, and this

```
var event;

if (this.off) {
   event = 'off';
} else {
   event = 'on';
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
var event = this.off ? 'off' : 'on';
```

---

**Added for the edited question :**

`jQuery()` or `$()` is a function, something we can tell from the parenthesis, so it's something like

```
function jQuery(arguments) {
    // do something
}
```

which can be called as

```
jQuery(some_arguments);
```

and as `var $ = jQuery` one can also do `$();`

Now that we know it's a function, it makes sense that we can do

```
$('#element_id')
```

and internally jQuery checks what kind of argument we passed, it sees that is's a string, and it's starting with `#`, so it's an ID, and then jQuery can do `document.getElementById()` and get that DOM element, and at the same it wraps that element in a new array-like object, usually referred to as a jQuery object.

We can also pass in a DOM node, array, object or anything else, and jQuery tries to figure out what it is, and wrap in that jQuery object for us to use with other jQuery methods, so this :

```
$({x:10, y:20})
```

is the same as

```
var obj = {x:10, y:20};

$(obj)
```

and its turned into one of those jQuery objects with the properties `x` and `y`. Passing in an object like this means we can chain on methods, and those properties are available in the methods.

```
$({x:10, y:20}).animate({x:50}, 1000);
```

And that's basically how it works, simplified a lot.

As for passing objects to methods, that's a very common way to pass arguments.
To see how it works, it's easiest to create a method:

```
$.fn.doStuff = function(argument) {
     this.css(argument);
}
```

inside a jQuery plugin, this is the jQuery object, and we can now use the mothod above that does nothing more than pass the arguments to jQuery's `css()`.
We know we can pass an object to `css()` like this :

```
$('#element').css({left: '10px', top: '20px'});
```

so using our plugin we can do the same

```
var obj = {left: '10px', top: '20px'};

$('#element').doStuff(obj);
```

and it ends up doing exactly the same thing. Of course, we could do anything with the object :

```
$.fn.doStuff = function(args) {
    if ( typeof args == 'string' ) {

          alert(args); // if it's a string, just alert it

    } else if ( typeof args == 'object' ) {

          for ( var key in args ) { // if it's an object, iterate

              this[0].style[key] = args[key]; // and do something

          }

    }
}
```

Comment: should `var event = on;` be `var event = 'on';`?

Comment: @lastr2d2 - was missing some quotes several places, think everything is in order now ?

Comment: Please see award description.

Comment: @C-link - There is no valid way I could think of that would use curlybraces after the selector, like this `$(selector){syntax}`, it just wouldn't make much sense. There's still a possibility that some framework or templating engine does it like that, but then you'd have to post an example and tell us exactly what's using that syntax, as it's not really something you'd use in plain javascript.

Comment: @C-link - Oh, but that's not `$(selector){curlybraces}` it's `$({object}).method({object})` which is valid.

Comment: @C-link - tried to explain it in the answer, see the added part ?

Comment: how about obj.animate(); than $(obj).animate(); like if var obj = $('div') then we would do obj.animate() here.... so for {...} is object so why $(obj) is used?

Comment: if you already have a jQuery object, you don't have to wrap it again, so if you have `var obj = $('div')` doing `$(obj).animate()` is not neccessary, you can do `obj.animate()` directly as it's already a jQuery object, but it won't break anything either.

Comment: what about this? .trigger('click', [true]); I mean equivalent to?

Answer (score 2):

`foo['bar']` syntax is to get the property `bar` from object `foo`.

`foo()` is to execute the function `foo`.

**And you can combine these as you wish.**

`jQuery.noConflict()` returns a function so you could execute the result by `jQuery.noConflict()(syntax)`.

`$(window)` returns an object so you could get a property from it by `$(window)[syntax]`, and if the property is a function, then you could execute it by `$(window)[syntax](syntax)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just javascript syntax.

`person.name` is **exactly** the same as `person["name"]`

The same happens with methods

`$(window).on(...)`  is **exactly** the same as `$(window)["on"](...)`

One cool thing about the second way is that you can make the member name variable, for example:

So doing:

```
var windowMethod = "on";
$(window)[windowMethod](...)
```

is the same as

```
$(window)["on"](...)
```

And you can have an expression inside the brackets, so this:

```
$(window)[this.off ? 'off' : 'on']("scroll", fixDiv );
```

would be exactly the same as doing this:

```
if(this.off)
    $(window).off("scroll", fixDiv);
else
    $(window).on("scroll", fixDiv);
```

But the former is shorter.

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: The `jQuery.noConflict()(syntax)` is straightforward, `.noConflict()` just returns a function and then we append some other parens to call it just as any other function.